# IObservable - Ignoring the prior result

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I have an IObservable which could be implemented as a BehaviorSubject, ReplaySubject or something similar.

In the following scenario I don't want the Subscriber to pick up the last cached value, instead I want it to pickup the next value to come through. Any ideas?

```
var subject = new BehaviorSubject(1);
subject.OnNext(2);

subject.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

subject.OnNext(3);
```

Note, the number I want printed is 3... I am guessing that I need to put one of the reactive extension methods between "subject.Subscribe" to get a new observable or something.

Comment: So you want to be able to get hot or cold observables and have them all act as if they're hot? Or is it only the *last* result you want to ignore?

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
var subject = new BehaviorSubject(1);
subject.OnNext(2);

subject
       .Skip(1) // 
       .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

subject.OnNext(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your specific snippet, you could just use a regular Subject and get what you want. Or for a generic cold Observable, you probably want `someSubject.Publish().RefCount()`

Comment: The example is very trivial, the problem is what if I am provided an I =Observable that happens to be BehaviorSubject... thats what I am trying to protect against.

Comment: @vdh_ant then Skip(1) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do it for you?

```
var subject = new BehaviorSubject<int>(1);

subject.OnNext(2);

var co = subject.Publish();

co.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

subject.OnNext(3);

co.Connect();
```